# i can't upload images using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to add a new product using ajax and bootstrap (modal) and when I press the `save changes` button, I get `Undefined index` in all the fields.

Here's my ajax code:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
    var desc = $('#desc').val();
    var precio = $('#precio').val();
    var stock = $('#stock').val();
    var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
    var data = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(jQuery('#imagen')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });
    var datas="nombre="+nombre+"&desc="+desc+"&precio="+precio+"&stock="+stock+"&tipo="+tipo;

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/newproduct.php",
        data: {datas, data},
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function( data ) {
        $('#info').html(data);
        viewdata();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }, 500);

        $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `data: {datas, data},` looks like invalid syntax for an object, should be a semicolon instead of a comma

Comment: Why not add all the data into the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object or just initialize it already with the form?

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {datas, data},
```

doesn't seem to be proper javascript syntax and I don't think you can mix different data object.
You can't mix `FormData` and an URL encoded string, which in your case isn't event properly encoded and you will have problems, if any of the values contains `&`.

The easiest way to upload using AJAX would be, if you initialized the `FormData` object with your `form`

```
var data = new FormData($("#form").get(0));
```

and then just used

```
data: data,
```

in your AJAX call

If you really need to add the fields manually, you need to add them to the `FormData` object

```
data.append("nombre", nombre);
data.append("desc ", desc);
data.append("precio ", precio);
data.append("stock ", stock);
data.append("tipo ", tipo);
```